# Sorting a Dictionary of dictioneris by some values and key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary of dictionaries by two values, 'Points' and 'win', then by the key. I can sort it based on 'Points' and 'win' like bellow but how can I sort it by the name as well?

```
my_dic = {
    'Iran': {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}, 
    'Spain': {'Points': 5, 'win': 1, 'lose': 0, 'drawes': 2, 'diffrence': 2}, 
    'Portugal': {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}, 
    'Morocco': {'Points': 3, 'win': 1, 'lose': 2, 'drawes': 0, 'diffrence': -2}
}
```

---

```
result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(my_dic.items(),key = lambda x: (x[1]['Points'],x[1]['win']), reverse = True) )
```

> Output:

```
OrderedDict([
    ('Spain', {'Points': 5, 'win': 1, 'lose': 0, 'drawes': 2, 'diffrence': 2}), 
    ('Iran', {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}), 
    ('Portugal', {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}), 
    ('Morocco', {'Points': 3, 'win': 1, 'lose': 2, 'drawes': 0, 'diffrence': -2})
])
```

my code already sorts the dict based on 'Points' and 'win'. But I expect the dict is sorted based on the keys, `Iran, Spain, Portugal, Moroco`, when the 'Points' and 'win' are equal.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(my_dic, key=lambda x: (my_dic[x]['Points'], my_dic[x]['win'], x),  
                     reverse=True)
print([(key, my_dic[key]) for key in sorted_keys])

Output: 

[('Spain', {'Points': 5, 'diffrence': 2, 'drawes': 2, 'lose': 0, 'win': 1}),
 ('Portugal', {'Points': 4, 'diffrence': 0, 'drawes': 1, 'lose': 1, 'win': 1}),
 ('Iran', {'Points': 4, 'diffrence': 0, 'drawes': 1, 'lose': 1, 'win': 1}),
 ('Morocco', {'Points': 3, 'diffrence': -2, 'drawes': 0, 'lose': 2, 'win': 1})]
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(my_dic.items(),key = lambda x: (-x[1]['Points'], -x[1]['win'], x[0])) )
```

That being said if you are sorting a `dict`... you probably shouldn't be using a `dict`...
Consider instead using something like a `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
my_dic = {
    'Iran': {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}, 
    'Spain': {'Points': 5, 'win': 1, 'lose': 0, 'drawes': 2, 'diffrence': 2}, 
    'Portugal': {'Points': 4, 'win': 1, 'lose': 1, 'drawes': 1, 'diffrence': 0}, 
    'Morocco': {'Points': 3, 'win': 1, 'lose': 2, 'drawes': 0, 'diffrence': -2}
}
Country = namedtuple("Country", "name stats")
Stats = namedtuple("Stats", "points win lose drawes difference")
countries = []
for key, value in my_dic.items():
    temp_stat = Stats(value["Points"], value["win"], value["lose"], value["drawes"], value["diffrence"])
    countries.append(Country(key, temp_stat))


def sort_funct(x):
    # The order in which we want to sort by
    return (-x.stats.points, -x.stats.win, x.name)

countries.sort(key=sort_funct)

for country in countries:
    print_str = "{} has {} points and {} wins".format(country.name, country.stats.points, country.stats.win)
    print(print_str)
```

**Output:**

```
Spain has 5 points and 1 wins
Iran has 4 points and 1 wins
Portugal has 4 points and 1 wins
Morocco has 3 points and 1 wins
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked out too. Thank you so much.